# Sort a JavaFX SortedList on Two Values

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a good way to add a default second sort to a JavaFX SortedList? What I want to do is allow the user to click the column headers as per the default, but have the value of my first column be the tie-breaker if the fist column was not selected. I would prefer to do this while still binding to the TableView comparatorProperty.

I was thinking of an implementation like something below:

```
SortedList<MyObj> sortedData = new SortedList<>(myFilteredList);
sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(myTableView.comparatorProperty()/*.thenComparing(otherComparator) or something like this*/);
```

Is there a way to bind on top of the read-only comparatorProperty of a TableView like this? Is there a better way?

Comment: `TableView` already supports sorting by multiple columns.By holding `Shift` you can add secondary sorts, see also [`TableView.getSortOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getSortOrder--)

Comment: This is true, but I want to create a default tie-breaker for my user without this additional step.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little clunky, but it seems to more or less do what you are looking for. The point is that if you use a sorted list, and allow clicking on the headers, you need to bind the comparator of the sorted list to the comparator of the table.

So I think the best bet is to modify the sort order defined by the table. Here's a simple way:

```
TableColumn<S,T> defaultSortColumn = ... ;
sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());

// Added an extra '>' for syntax
table.getSortOrder().addListener((Change<? extends TableColumn<S,?>> c) -> {
    if (table.getSortOrder().size() != 2 || table.getSortOrder().get(1) != defaultSortColumn) {
        table.getSortOrder().setAll(table.getSortOrder().get(0), defaultSortColumn);
    }
});
```

(Obviously replace `S` and `T` by the appropriate types.)

Comment: This compiled and ran, but it caused the column headers to appear unresponsive. Is there away to fix that explicitly?

Comment: @Agricola See update... Not sure if that is what you're looking for but it might give you a start. Feels a bit of a hack.